# Passing selected option to controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a table that has some inputs and angular models.

```
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" id="">
                                    <option ng-model="mfrNo" ng-repeat="manufacturer in manufacturers" value="mfrNo">{{manufacturer.SUPP_NAME}} [{{manufacturer.SUPP_NO}}]</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="newCon" class="form-control" name="new_contract_number" value="" maxlength="500"/>
                            </td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="reassignContract()">Reassign</button>
```

In my controller I want to retrieve the values that are selected/inputted.

```
    $scope.reassignContract = function () {
        console.log($scope.newCon);
        console.log($scope.mfrNo);

    };
```

The first model `newCon` passes the text input fine. But the 2nd, `mfrNo` outputs undefined/null.

Why is this model/object not passing? What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngModel` should go on the `<select>` not the `<option>`.  You should also consider using [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

So:

```
<td>
    <!-- ngModel should go here -->
    <select ng-model="mfrNo" class="form-control" id="">
        <!-- Instead of here -->
        <option ng-repeat="manufacturer in manufacturers" value="mfrNo">{{manufacturer.SUPP_NAME}} [{{manufacturer.SUPP_NO}}]</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Additionally, you are setting the `value` of your only `<option>` to "mfrNo".  I don't know if that is intentional or not, but that means that the value of `$scope.mfrNo` will be `"mfrNo"`.  I think you mean to set it to some other value from the `$scope`.  Use `{{some_scope_var}}` interpolation.

Comment: I'm getting something returning now but it's the string 'mfrNo' not the selected input.

Comment: It looks like it's from value="mfrNo".

Comment: @DavidTunnell See my additional comment.  It's because the actual value of that `<option>` is the String literal "mfrNo".  You need to use interpolation if you aren't going to use ngOptions.

Comment: @DavidTunnell I'm guessing it needs to be `value = "{{manufacturer.SUPP_NO}}"`?